# Is there any way to check if ssh root login is disabled

Tags: ssh

In sshd_config, we can set

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

to disable root login.

I am writing a script to check server config. Is there any way to check/test this, without check the `sshd_config` file, since this file requires `sudo` privilege?

Comment: Try to login as root?

Comment: I am writing a script to check several configurations. so I am afraid I cannot try it manually. (thanks)

Comment: To check configurations, you normally need root privileges. This setting can only be queried by checking `sshd_config`, or perhaps the systemd journal (or other `sshd` log, depending on setup). Thus, you need to have read access to those resources, which is normally limited to root.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the correct credentials and remote root log in succeeds you know that your sshd is not configured correctly (or it wasn’t restarted).

When you can’t log in you don’t learn anything conclusive.

By design sshd (and most other tools) shouldn’t leak privileged security information.

A remote attacker should not be able to learn (because of a specific error message) that a username is valid or not, even when they don’t have the correct credentials for that user.

Therefor  there should be  no difference in the external error message you get for any combination where not all three conditions provided are true:

- a username is valid
- the user is permitted to log in
- the password, private key or other credentials you are using is valid for that user

That holds true root as well as any other user.

Note that the error messages logged on the server can potentially be and usually are different for each reason why access is denied; but reading those error messages will require admin rights too ...

—————

In other words: the only definitive checks possible to confirm that your servers are configured correctly will require privileged access to the servers concerned.